# Banco de dados nao retornando nenhum valor

Tags: php, mysql, query, mysqli, select

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE 
          (suite LIKE '%".$suites."%' 
           OR banheiro LIKE '%".$banheiro."%'
           OR quarto LIKE '%".$quarto."%' 
           OR garagem LIKE '%".$garagens."%')

           AND (motivo LIKE '%".$tipo1."%'  
           OR tipo LIKE '%".$tipo."%')
           AND cidade LIKE '%".$cidadd."%' 
           AND estado LIKE '%".$local."%' 
           AND preco >= '$valor' 
           AND tamanho <= '$tamanho' ";

        $anunciarRadio=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
```

O que eu **preciso é que retorne a as casas na mesma cidadade da minha variavel** com determinado com os valores de quantidade de garagem, suites, banheiros, quartos aproximados, com o valor de preço inferior variavel **$valor**, e tamanho superior a variavel **$tamanho.**

O que estou fazendo de errado??

Ao colocar os valores exatamente iguais aos gravados no banco de dados ele nao me retorna nada... 
sera que é erro de  sintaxe ou logica ?

Quando coloco tudo para or  ele retorna porem vem todos.
Ou seja preciso de um pente fino, porem nem tanto, preciso nao priorizar alguns campos como quartos, banheiros, garagem,suite e o restante priorizar como sendo exato...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso aqui

```
       AND preco >= '$valor' 
       AND tamanho <= '$tamanho' ";
```

não seria assim?

```
       AND preco >= '" .$valor. "' 
       AND tamanho <= '" .$tamanho. "'";
```

Corrigindo seu select:
Sobre o BETWEEN: [Voce pode ver melhor aqui aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

```
     $sql="SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE 
      (suite BETWEEN ".($suites - 2)." AND ".($suites + 2)."
       OR banheiro BETWEEN ".($banheiro - 2)." AND ".($banheiro + 2)."
       OR quarto BETWEEN ".($quarto - 2)." AND ".($quarto + 2)." 
       OR garagem BETWEEN ".($garagens - 2)." AND ".($garagens + 2).")

       AND (motivo LIKE '%".$tipo1."%'  
       OR tipo LIKE '%".$tipo."%')
       AND cidade LIKE '%".$cidadd."%' 
       AND estado LIKE '%".$local."%' 
       AND preco >= '".$valor."' 
       AND tamanho <= '".$tamanho."' ";
```

Pelo que entendi vc quer que os numero de garagem, suítes, banheiros, quartos sejam próximos do que o usuário digitou logo isso serve para fazer isso:

```
// supon que suites sejam 4
suite BETWEEN ".($suites - 2)." AND ".($suites + 2)."
// Nessa parte abaixo eu diminuo 2 para que ele procure apartir de 2  
".($suites - 2)." 
// ate 6. aqui eu aumento 2 para o valor ser 6
".($suites + 2)."
```

Resumindo o código irá retorna se o numero do imóvel seja entre 2 e 6.
Espero que tenha ficado claro e ajudado você agora.

ps: não manjo de php então não tenho certeza que `.($suites - 2).` seja operação correta, mas acho que sim por nas outra linguagens são assim um ,abraço. :D

Comment: fiz essa correção e continua nao vindo nada., acredito que seja referente ao AND e OR @.@ estava estudando o uso deles mas nao entendi corretamente, como usar da forma descrita acima com aspas podendo deixar alguns campos como nao tao necessario e outros como sendo obrigatoriamente igua, porem podendo ter erros gramaticais

Comment: Bom vou tentar passa pra ti de forma rápida, AND vc usa quando quer que o valor retornado seja aquilo que a variável de comparação contenha se não contiver não irá retornar, ou seja se no seu código se o 'imovel' que vc esta procurando no select tiver todas as variáveis iguais a da comparação ou no caso do 'AND var like %algo%' o valor 'var' estiver contido dentro de 'algo' ele irá retornar oimovel, agora se alguma variavel da comparação AND retornar false, ou seja não contiver, o seu select não irá retornar nada.

Comment: Veja que não falei do OR pois o OR é mais simples se ele achar o valor ele retorna porém se ele não encontrar o valor correspondente ele não irá retornar se ele estiver comparando sozinho. 
Exemplo "select * from imoveis where 1 = 0 OR nome like '%nameImovel%' "
Aqui o where 1=0 é so para sempre ser 0(false) ou seja se o OR for 1 ele retornar e for 0 ele não retorna nada.
No caso do se select se apenas o OR for verdadeiro ele não irá retornar e se apenas o OR for false e os AND forem verdadeiros ele irá retornar

Comment: Resumindo AND so retornará quando as todas as condições forem Verdadeiras.
OR retornará quando alguma das condições forem atendidas.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta veja se agora pode ser de ajuda.

Comment: Funcionou obrigado.. era isso que estava em duvida.. perfeito parabéns obrigado.

Comment: que isso disponha, fico feliz em poder ajudar :D

Answer (score 0):

essa variável é assim mesmo?

```
AND cidade LIKE '%".$cidadd."%'
```

e o exemplo do amigo @Will pode ser assim tb.

```
AND preco >= '{$valor}' 
AND tamanho <= '{$tamanho}'";
```

Comment: opa, a variavel é assim mesmo, acredito que seja referente ao AND e OR @.@  estava estudando o uso deles mas nao entendi corretamente, como usar da forma descrita acima com aspas podendo deixar alguns campos como nao tao necessario e outros como sendo obrigatoriamente igua, porem podendo ter erros gramaticais.